# How to bind items of a TabControl to an observable collection in wpf?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, tabcontrol, observablecollection

What is the simplest example of binding the items of a TabControl to an ObservableCollection?

Each tab's content will have unique data, and indeed this data will have observableCollections of its own bound to the items components.

Currently I have a user control, which I would like to set as the content of each tab as soon as it is created. I also need to dynamically set the datacontext of this new user control when the tab is created. So, essentially, I would like the tabcontrol's observablecollection contain modelviews that map to the data in each tab.

On top of that, I need to do all this without violating MVVM in WPF! Any help?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Basic example :

```
<Window.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="templateForTheContent" DataType="{x:Type vm:TheViewModelType}">
        <v:YourUserControl/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="templateForTheHeader" DataType="{x:Type vm:TheViewModelType}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ThePropertyToDisplayInTheHeader}"/>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>

...

<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}"
            ContentTemplate="{StaticResource templateForTheContent}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource templateForTheHeader}">
</TabControl>
```

Comment: You know, WPF + MVVM has such a steep learning curve, but once you get the hang of it the solutions are actually very elegant and clean. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I agree that WPF has a steep learning curve, but I wouldn't say that about the MVVM pattern... actually it feels quite natural when you start using it :)

Comment: As long as the data templates contain only read-only controls, this approach works. Otherwise, you must be careful: the TabControl recreates the view every time you change the tab page, i.e. you are losing the visual state when you switch from one tab to another and then switch back again.

Comment: Would this work if I have several `ViewModel` types in the bound collection?

Comment: @Onur, yes. In this case, don't put an `x:Key` attribute on the DataTemplate, and create a different DataTemplate for each item type