# How to bind WPF TabControl ContentTemplate to an observable collection of different ViewModels

Tags: wpf, binding, tabcontrol

I know this question has been asked and answered several times already but I still don't get it. I seem to be missing a piece of understanding.

I have a TabControl bound to an observable list of viewmodels. The viewmodels can be of different types, derived from the same base type, of course. When a viewmodel is added to the list I want the tabcontrol adds a new tabpage based on the type of the view model.

I do not understand how to set up the ContentTemplate of the TabControl to pick the right view based on the type of the view model.

A Basic example can be found here, but I do not get it up and running with dynamic views:

[How to bind items of a TabControl to an observable collection in wpf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261118/how-to-bind-items-of-a-tabcontrol-to-an-observable-collection-in-wpf)

Thanks! Johannes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, i will modify the sample code in the answer you linked:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="templateForTheHeader" DataType="{x:Type vm:BaseViewModel}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CommonPropertyToDisplayInTheHeader}"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ViewModel1}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyInVM1}"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ViewModel2}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyInVM2}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

...

<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource templateForTheHeader}">
</TabControl>
```

The header displays some property in the base VM class.
And the important thing, i removed the `x:key` of the other DataTemplates, this will make it being applied to every instance of the defined `DataType` found in the `Window` (`ContentTemplate` in the `TabControl` not needed).

`YourCollection` is a mix of objects, each of it will get its template applied based on its type if a `DataTemplate` with matching `DataType` exists. Simple uh?

Comment: Saved my day. But magic is bad. If you don't know how to achieve this, you will never get on the right track by reading just the docs or scouring through IntelliSense. Sorry MS your doc sucks, as well as implicit magic stuff.