# How to get textblock name for the selected TabItem from TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf

I create dynamically 5 types TabItem for TabControl. For example:

```
 <Style x:Key="StyleCrcs" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="True"/>
        <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseMove" Handler="TabItem_PreviewMouseMove"/>
        <EventSetter Event="Drop" Handler="TabItem_Drop"/>
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" >
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Adres(hex)" FontSize="15" Margin="10,10,396,444"/>
                        <ComboBox x:Name="AddressCrcs" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="134,11,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
                            <ComboBoxItem>60</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>61</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>62</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>63</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>64</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>65</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>66</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>67</ComboBoxItem>
                        </ComboBox>

                        <TextBlock x:Name="Tranz1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Tranzystor 1:" FontSize="15" Margin="10,126,396,337"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="Tranz2" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Tranzystor 2:" FontSize="15" Margin="10,156,396,307"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Each for them have specific constructions.
All of this types inheritance from ICards.

```
interface ICards
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Address { get; set; }
}
class CardCrcs : ICards
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Tranzystor1 { get; set; }
    public string Tranzystor2 { get; set; }
}
```

When i create TabItem i add object to list.

Each TabItem has textblocks and I want set text for this textblocks when i change TabItem.

How can i do that?

```
<TabControl x:Name="TabCards" Grid.Column="1" SelectionChanged="TabCards_SelectionChanged">

var list = new List<ICards>()
var element = (CardCrcs)list[0];
TabCards.SelectedItem.Tranz1.Text = element.Tranzystor1;
```

`TabCards.SelectedItem.Tranz1.Text`dont work. How replace this to do that?

EDIT:

When i do that i can take header, but cant take textblock name.

```
var item = (TabItem)TabCards.SelectedItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest binding your TabControl to a list of view model instances for which you also provide DataTemplates (that would map as tab item's ContentTemplate).

See [this question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37410148/how-to-bind-wpf-tabcontrol-contenttemplate-to-an-observable-collection-of-differ) for reference.

You seem to already have different view models defined (e.g. CardCrcs class), so you can define DataTemplate objects with TargetType set for each of them, describing how each tab item should look like.

Inside each of these templates you can use Bindings to properties that are defined by the corresponding classes, e.g. `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}"/>`.

Finally, set ItemsSource of TabControl to a list of view model instances that you can prepared in your DataContext if that is your wish: `ItemsSource={Binding}`.

This approach would limit a lot the code behind, and would be also easier to understand, IMO.

Comment: I not sure i good understand you. The reason why i did this is. The user select which, how much and in which order add Cards. So i thought it will ok to define whole tabitem's. Thanks for reply and sugestions.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I was too specific. Here is some [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview) and a [guide](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/wpf/legacy/Implementing-MVVM.html) for understanding bindings and MVVM approach in WPF (the concepts are used in my answer). You don't need every info from there, but try to get an overview. The latter link points to older resources but concepts still apply.